# System of SDE in R

Tags: r, differential-equations, montecarlo, stochastic

Let

```
dXt = -Yt dt +cos(Xt + Yt)/(sqrt(t+1))*dW1_t
dYt =  Xt dt +sin(Xt + Yt)/(sqrt(t+1))*dW2_t

X0=1, Y0=1, T=1,
```

(W1_t, W2_t) is a Brownian Motion in dimension 2.

Could someone tell me how I could implement this system of SDEs in R?

I tried it with

```
library(Sim.DiffProc)
set.seed(1234)
fx <- expression(-y , x )
gx <- expression(cos(x+y)/sqrt(t+1),sin(x+y)/sqrt(t+1))
mod2d1 <-snssde2d(drift=fx,diffusion=gx,x0=c(x0=1,y0=1),M=1000)
```

the default solver in this package here is Euler Maruyama.What I need to calculate is Expected Value ((X_T)^2+(Y_T)^2) (with a different discretiziations and compare it with the analytic solution for this expected value. My question would be, how can I calculate this expected value of the sum of squares of the processes? summary(mod) gives me the mean, but how can I get the result that I want? do I have to square the expressions prior to input them to the solver?

Comment: `BM` means what?

Comment: @PeaceWang: brownian motion, will edit it

Comment: The middle terms have no differentials, or should the last `+` be a `*` in each equation? Otherwise reading the documentation of the SDE solver library should give a rather straight-forward implementation, you should be able to modify one of the documentation examples.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: thank you, of course it should have been a ‚*‘. I tried with sde.sim, but did not manage it. Would there been another way? Is it also possible to do it without any library? As I will later also be trying to implement the Euler Maruyama solver manually.

Comment: You should then probably report on your try with sde.sim, as far as you got, on your efforts at debugging this and what the errors were.

Comment: With a non-scalar Brownian path you will hit a steep cliff for anything beyond Euler-Maruyama, so it is better to use an established library. It can be helpful to have tests that can confirm that the claimed weak and strong orders of the method are actually reached.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Thank you very much for coming back to this question, I edited my post, In fact I used a different package now.